# python list index out of range while reading rows out of excel file

Tags: python-3.x

i want to read out the whole rows in an excel-file. I dont know how much rows there are.

i have the following Code:

```
import xlrd
import sys
from time import *


wb = xlrd.open_workbook("RBU_COIN.xlsx")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

rows =[]
n = 1
t1 = clock()
for row_number in range(sh.nrows):
    rows.append(sh.row_values(row_number))
    n = n + 1

for row in rows[n]:
    print(row)
t2 = clock()


t = t2 - t1
print('Rechenzeit: ', t)
```

After executing i get the error that in line 16 is an IndexError: list index out of range.

I cant find the mistake i made.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i try to read out the row values of an excel-file. But i dont know how much rows the file contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over `rows` like this:

```
# ...
for row in rows:
    print(row)
# ...
```

Comment: thanks but i tried that already and got the same error. Now i changed
for row in rows[n]: in for row in rows[:]: and it worked! But maybe its not the best way to solve that.

Comment: Yeah you don't need to iterate over a copy when you can iterate over the original.